# Vue CDN doesn't seem to be working with jsdeliver or the cdn provided by the documentation

Tags: vue.js

Im following a guide on vue.js but the cdn doesnt seem to be working.

I tried the cdn directly from the documentation instead of the one provided by the guide and it still doesnt seem to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <input type="text" v-model="name"/>
        <p>Hello {{ name }}</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data(){
                return{
                    name: 'John'
                };
            }
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From opening `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue` directly in a browser

> Original file: /npm/**vue@3.2.47**/dist/vue.global.js

The CDN is for Vue 3, but the code you're trying to run is specific to Vue 2.  The actual [Vue 2 docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Getting-Started) specify an appropriate CDN to use: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>`

If you want to use Vue 3 (the recommended version), the [Vue 3 docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#using-vue-from-cdn) include the correct code needed to get started with a basic app:

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">{{ message }}</div>

<script>
  const { createApp } = Vue

  createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    }
  }).mount('#app')
</script>
```

Notice the use of `createApp()` instead of Vue 2's `new Vue()`